# mplayer: looking for the correct syntax of a certain command

Tags: command-line, mplayer

I found out that **mplayer** supports an **equalizer** option natively.

The command `mplayer -af equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:10:10 sound-file.wav` generally works fine. It produces much crisper audio.

But: **Some** wav-files have a sample-rate that is too low for that process. Terminal says:

> [equalizer] Limiting the number of filters to 8 due to low sample
> rate.

So the equalizer option has no effect.

On http://mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/MPlayer.html I found an interesting comment:

> Sample Rate Conversion:
>
> If the audio sample rate in the original file is not the same as
> required by the target format, sample rate conversion is required.
> This is achieved using the -srate option and the -af lavcresample
> audio filter together.

This is the example they give:

```
DVD:

-srate 48000 -af lavcresample=48000
```

Now I´m not dealing with a DVD here but a mere *audio-file*. So I tried two different commands:

`mplayer -srate 44100 -af equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:10:10 sound-file.wav`
and

```
mplayer -srate 44100  -af lavcresample=44100 -af equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:10:10 sound-file.wav
```

Both work equally well and produce an exit code of "0". And both have the desired effect of making the equalizer kick in.

So my question is:

What do you think, which syntax is the correct one and which should I use?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Many greetings.
Rosika

P.S.:
my system: Linux/Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Maybe just me but this is a question about mplayer not anything about Lubuntu.

Comment: @David: Hi. Well, I thought I'd post it here anyway as there seem to be more mplayer-related questions in the forum. Greetings.